# Impedir alterações css com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

eu tenho uma div com a classe **footer** quando vou estiliza-la no css e deixo em display: none; desaparece ate ai tudo bem. mas queria que quando utilizado css para ocultar essa div ela não sofrer nenhum efeito. Ex:

```
 .footer {
   display:none !important;
}
```

mesmo com a tag ***!important*** eu quero que essa classe não sofra alterções. Eu ja tentei com uma tag javascript.

```
document.getElementById('.footer').style.display="block";
```

E com JQuery

```
$('.footer').css('display','block');
```

Resumindo eu quero forçar com javascript a essa classe não sofrer efeitos.

Comment: Sua dúvida não faz muito sentido, porque se você não quer que sofra alterações, basta você simplesmente não faze-las.

Comment: @LuizFelipe pensei a mesma coisa

Comment: o objetivo e que quem possua meu template não possa modifica-las

Comment: Tá aí um bom recurso para disponibilizar no CSS 4 (se é que já não está finalizado). Boa oportunidade para você contribuir nessa implementação na nova versão =)

Comment: uma vez no browser a tela  pertence ao usuário pode fazer o que quiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso reescrevendo o estilo com jQuery quando a página é carregada. Use `cssText` com `!important` que irá anular a referência do elemento no CSS.

Por exemplo, quero que o texto da `div` seja sempre azul. Veja que no CSS abaixo coloquei para ficar vermelho (`#f30 !important`). Quando a página é carregada, o jQuery irá refazer o estilo com os valores que eu quiser:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".footer").css("cssText","color: #00f !important");
});
```

```css
.footer{
   color: #f30 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">Texto sempre azul</div>
```

Com JavaScript puro, você usa `setProperty`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   let el = document.querySelector(".footer");
   el.style.setProperty("color", "#00f", "important");
});
```

```css
.footer{
   color: #f30 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">Texto sempre azul</div>
```

> Só lembrando que isso não dá garantia nenhuma. Qualquer pessoa com conhecimento poderá alterar, sobrescrever ou remover o código.

Answer (score 0):

O pessoal pode achar estranho, mas eu já passei por isso, no meu caso não era alterar e sim capturar essa DIV junta no DOM quando lê o corpo todo do HTML.

Eu acredito que ele queira modificar o conteúdo do `document.body`, mas quer manter a DIV em questão.

Pra não ter que alterar o código todo que você já deve ter criado, eu posso dar uma solução, salve o conteúdo do **FOOTER** numa variável, assim nem vai precisar ocultar ela com CSS:

```
var footer = document.getElementById('.footer').outerHTML;
```

Segue o exemplo:

```js
var footer;
function novapagina(){
   footer = document.getElementById('footer').outerHTML;
   alert('Nova página');
   document.body.innerHTML = "NOVO CONTEUDO";
   alert('Inserir rodapé');
   document.body.innerHTML += footer;
}
```

```html
<h1>HEADER</h1>
<input type="button" onclick="novapagina()" value="Nova página" /><br />
<p id="footer">MEU RODAPE FIXO</p>
```